# jQuery, Prepend data from input not working

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML-markup:

```
<div id="destination">

</div>

<input id="test" type="text" />

<button id="clicker">Click me</button>​
```

And this jQuery-snippet

```
$(document).on('click', '#clicker', function(event){

    var newCat = $('#test').val();
    $(newCat).prepend("#destination");
       alert(newCat);
 });​
```

The alerted text is indeed the inputed text in the field, but the text does not end up in the div `#destination`.

See this jsfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/FaAY4/

Comment: Why are you delegating the event to `document`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#clicker', function(event){

    var newCat = $('#test').val();
    $("#destination").prepend(newCat );
       alert(newCat);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! In my original file (before I made the jsfiddle) I used prependTo. Anyways, your answer works :)

Answer (score 2):

You're using `prepend()` incorrectly. The syntax is:

```
$(targetElement).prepend(newContent);
```

Used like this in your specific example:

```
$("#destination").prepend(newCat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to add an elemet to a value?

```
var newCat = $('#test').val();
```

The above line will give you the value of the text box.

```
$(newCat)
```

Will not correspond to any element.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are swapping source and destination i.e.:

```
$(document).on('click', '#clicker', function(event){
    var newCat = $('#test').val();
    $('#destination').prepend(newCat);
       alert(newCat);
});​
```

[Fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/FaAY4/2/)